# How to run animation in background?

Tags: android, animation, background

I have a menu with some basic buttons and some translate animations.
I wonder how you can run the animations in the background so the buttons still are visible when the animation is running?[image]

Code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);


    image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.greenbox);
    image2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.redbox);
    image3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.purplebox);

            // Animations

        image1.setAnimation(mAnimation);
        image2.setAnimation(mAnimation);
        image3.setAnimation(mAnimation2);

    butPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
    butHow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonHow);
    butOptions = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOptions);
    butPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
    butHow.setOnClickListener(this);
    butOptions.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: the animations should run on the foreground: on uithread

Comment: I upaded the question. I want the red block appearing on how to play in the background so a blue button still remains blue.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you mean that the thing that you are animating is being drawn over the buttons, so that you can't see them?

In which case, the order that your views are added to your layout are the order in which they are drawn (and intercept touch events), so move the buttons to be added after what is being animated (this is either the order in your xml file, or the order (/index) you add via code).

Comment: I did that. I first started the animations and then did findviewbyid with the buttons so the buttons are added at the end. But still doesn't change the problem

Comment: I changed the order in XML and that appears to work (doesn't work in code). It's working now the images are behind the buttons. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the Animation's onPreExecute() function, and then set the Z-order of the Button to ZORDER_TOP

That will force the Button to come to the front of the screen and the animation should be played behind it.